# How can I add an opaque overlay over the image on box decoration in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am struggling to come up with a solution to this seemingly simple task. I need an opaque overlay over an image in Flutter. I have tried to add the overlay different ways, but the image will always overlay on top of whatever I do. Mind you I need the opaque overlay over the image, but not over the title or text that sits on top of both the image and the overlay. Alternatively, I could have a black background and make the image opaque resulting possibly in the same effect that I want to achieve? Before I start to hack too much I would like to see how pros are doing it the way it should be done. Thank you all for your kind advices.

```
                  Container(
                    width: 320.0,
                    height: 180.0,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        image: NetworkImage(
                            news[index]['jetpack_featured_media_url'],
                        ),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                      color: Color(0xFF1F1F98),
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                        begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                        colors: [Colors.black, Colors.black],
                        stops: [0.0, 0.5]
                      ),
                      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: const Radius.circular(8.0),
                          topRight: const Radius.circular(8.0)
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                        child: Text(
                            cardTitle(news[index]['title']['rendered']),
                            style: kCardOverlayTitleTextStyle
                        )
                    ) /* add child content here */,
                  ),
```

Comment: try Color(0xFF1F1F98).withOpacity(0.5)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the ColorFilter option available in the DecoratedImage Widget

```
Container(
          width: 320.0,
          height: 180.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: NetworkImage(news[index['jetpack_featured_media_url']),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
               colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
                BlendMode.darken
               ),
           ),
         ),
```

Comment: I have used BlendMode.darken and set the withOpacity to 0.7, it works! Thanks

Comment: I think for overlay `BlendMode.srcOver` will be correct.

Answer (score 0):

`BlendMode.srcOver` composite the source image over the destination image. So, if you want to add the overlay, this will be the option of choice. You can find more about this blend mode [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/BlendMode.html#srcOver)

Here is the snippet that will work:

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
      image: const AssetImage('../your-image.png'),
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
        Colors.red.withOpacity(0.8),
        BlendMode.srcOver,
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```